# Clear select option after successful submit

Tags: php

```
<div class="select_list">
    <div class="labels">Category:</div>
    <?php
        if(!isset($_POST['postbtn)){
            echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){
                $('.category').val(0);
            })
            </script>";
        }
        echo "<select name='category' id='catg_list' class='list_catg'>
            <option value='0'";
                if(isset($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category']=='0'){
                    echo "selected";
                }
            echo">none</option>";
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, name from table1");
            while($query_fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                echo "<option value='".$query_fetch['id']."'";
                if(isset($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category']==$query_fetch['id'])
                {
                    echo "selected";
                }
                echo ">".$query_fetch['name']."</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";
    ?>
</div>
```

> The problem with the above code is that the selected element stays selected after the submission is done. I need the select option to return back to 'none' when the form is submitted successfully. How can that be done?

Comment: It looks like you are checking to see if the value is set to 0 by default? why not just set the value to 0 by default. That way no matter what when the page loads it will be set to none

Comment: Actually I have more fields like textfields in the form which are required to be filled properly before the submission. Now if someone enters wrong data in one of the textfields the submission should be stopped but in that case the user if has selected an element, that should remain selected and only should reset to 'none' when the submission is error free.

Answer (score 0):

You have an syntax error in your line:

```
if(!isset($_POST['postbtn)){
```

change it to:

```
if(!isset($_POST['postbtn'])){
```

I'm guessing some things you didn't mention:
You validate your script above the code you posted, and you want - if the script was validated successfully - that the "none" option is selected.

```
$selected_value = $validation ? $_POST['category'] : false;
```

Only if the Validation is correct the value will be set, else it will be set to false;

```
<?php
echo "<select name='category' id='catg_list' class='list_catg'>
        <option value='0'"; 
//CHANGE
            if($selected_value == 0){ //Or if($selected_value === FALSE ||$selected_value === 0)
                echo "selected";
            }
        echo">none</option>";
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, name from table1");
        while($query_fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            echo "<option value='".$query_fetch['id']."'";
//CHANGE
            if($selected_value !== FALSE && $selected_value == $query_fetch['id'])
            {
                echo "selected";
            }
            echo ">".$query_fetch['name']."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your code as following to do required task.

```
    $category = isset($_POST['category']) ? $_POST['category'] : 0;

    $array["0"]="none";
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, name from table1");
    while($query_fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $id = $query_fetch['id'];
        $array[$id] =  $query_fetch['name'];
    }

    echo "<select name='category' id='catg_list' class='list_catg'>";
    foreach($array as $id=>$name) {
        $selected = $category==$id ? "selected" : "";
        echo "<option value='".$id."' ".$selected." >".$name."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
```